# modulo group of prime order

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, modules

$p$ is prime of the form $p=2^{n}+1$ for $n\in N$. How can I show that $o(2)=2n$ for $2\in Z_{p}$?

And how can I proove that $n=2^{k}$ for some $k\in N$?

For the first, the only clue that I see that from theorem: $$$$
$(2,p)=1$ then $2^{\phi(p)}=1$ and $\phi(p)=p-1$ then $\phi(2^{n}+1)=2^n$
so generally: $$2^{2^{n}}=1$$

**Edited: Second part of the question**
$$n=2^{k}|k\in N$$
How do I prove that ?

Comment: I fear that both parts of this question have already been asked a few times here on MSE.

Comment: Jack, maybe you can public a link for them ?

Comment: For the second question, if $n=ab$ with $a$ odd, then $2^n+1$ is divisible by $2^b+1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $2^n\equiv -1$ mod $(2^n+1)$.

Comment: ok, so $2^{-1}≡1(mod(p))$, I tried to continue developing the algebraic calculations. but I didn't get any result, can you write the continuation ?

Comment: @Ilya.K. Don't click the green checkmark on answers until you're a satisfied customer. Since $2^n\equiv-1$, you know $2^{2n}\equiv 1$. Can you prove $2$ cannot have order smaller than $2n$? Suppose it did have order smaller than $2n$, and see what happens. Tip: its order $k$ cannot be $\le n$ itself, because then $2^k-1$ is smaller hence cannot be a multiple of $2^n+1$.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Hm...what is the objection there, assuming that the order is less then 2n?
Will we get something that devides $p$? 
I dont see clearly.

Comment: @Ilya.K. Suppose $2^k\equiv 1$ and $2^{2n}\equiv 1$ with $n<k<2n$. That means $2^{2n-k}\equiv 1$ doesn't it?

Comment: And what bother's us in the last conclusion? 
Secondly, ok' let the conclusion that there isn't such k ($n<k<2n$)? don't we need to show in that case that the option $0<k<n$ also don't fit ? 
Or is it trivial and I don't see it ?

Comment: @Ilya.K. I already explained in my first comment why $k\le n$ is not possible. I also nudged you how to see why $n<k<2n$ was problematic in my second comment (don't just stare at $2^{2n-k}\equiv1$; think about it). All the pieces to the puzzle have now been laid on the table, all you need to do is put them together. I am not going to do your problem for you - you need to do some part of it!